SQL Error primary key not null how to fix
I am trying to insert a SQL code to my database for gta v fivem server but I get an error.
Code:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gloveboxitems`
(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `plate` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `items` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`plate`),
    KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stashitems` 
(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `stash` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `items` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`stash`),
    KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trunkitems` 
(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `plate` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `items` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`plate`),
    KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `player_vehicles` 
(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `license` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `citizenid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `vehicle` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `hash` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `mods` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
    `plate` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `fakeplate` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `garage` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `fuel` int(11) DEFAULT 100,
    `engine` float DEFAULT 1000,
    `body` float DEFAULT 1000,
    `state` int(11) DEFAULT 1,
    `depotprice` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `drivingdistance` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `status` text DEFAULT NULL,
    `balance` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `paymentamount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `paymentsleft` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `financetime` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `plate` (`plate`),
    KEY `citizenid` (`citizenid`),
    KEY `license` (`license`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

Error:

SQL Error (1171): All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead

I try all I could found on google, don't really know

The error's complaint is about having plate as the primary key but that cannot be null. You can, however, specify plate as a unique key as the error suggests.

Primary key means that the values in that column (or combination of columns, if there are more than one columns in the primary key) are unique and not null.
Let's examine the gloveboxitems table for example (the same issue repeats in the other tables too. plate should be a primary key, but it's nullable, which won't fly. You could either define it as not nullable:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gloveboxitems`
(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `plate` varchar(255), -- Here
    `items` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`plate`),
    KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Alternatively, if you want the values to be unique but allow nulls, you can use a unique constraint instead of a primary key:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gloveboxitems`
(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `plate` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `items` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
    UNIQUE (`plate`), -- Here!
    KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

